# Default value of Point type

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, geospatial

In Laravel migrations, what should I use as the default value of `Point` type column? I originally wanted to keep it `NULL` but then I [read](https://packagist.org/packages/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial) that:

> > Columns in spatial indexes must be declared NOT NULL.

So what should I use as the default value of my column and how do I specify that in migration, to represent `NULL`, something like `0,0` or `-1,-1`?

```
$table->point('location')->default(???);
```

**UPDATE**

Doing more research, I found an even bigger issue. MySQL doesn't allow specifying default value for `POINT` type column. So I must insert a `NULL`-equivalent at `INSERT` time. What would be the correct value for this purpose?

Comment: @Downvoter: Sometimes I just wonder...

Comment: maybe `->point('location')` instead of `->point(location')`?

Comment: @Egretos: Yep. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Kyslik: Yep. Really really. I'm using GoDaddy's shared hosting and MySQL is my only option.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30816278/4848587? Looks like you have to choose a default value depending on your use case.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir: Thanks for the pointer. No, I didn't see this before. Looks like many people are struggling with the same issue. I was going to use `(-1000, -1000)` as my null value, but was not sure if MySQL would be happy with that. Looks like North Pole is cold enough to be set as null. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is you case, but if you are trying to add a column to an existing table, and then add a spatial index to that on a migration, the way I find to address this in MySQL was not an elegant solution, but worked:

```
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    // Add the new nullable column
    $table->point('column')->nullable();
});
// You must separate this to ensure the execution order
Schema::table('table', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    // Insert the dummy values on the column
    DB::statement("UPDATE `table` SET `column` = POINT(0,90);");
    // Set the column to not null
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `column` `column` POINT NOT NULL;");

    // Finally add the spatial index
    $table->spatialIndex('column');
});
```

Comment: This worked for me! I also tried to change the column to non-nullable by $table->point('column')->nullable(false)->change(), but this throws an error. So, I had to do it by raw SQL like in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using MariaDB, I could insert it successfully with:

->default(DB::raw("POINT(0,90)"))

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately my web host didn't support MariaDB. MySQL was my only option.